# Failed to create prime the NuGet cache, dotnet restore.

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm writing application .Net Core in VS 2017.
When using the dotnet restore command, I get a message

```
    Configuring...
-------------------
A command is running to initially populate your local package cache, to improve restore speed and enable offline access. This command will take up to a minute to complete and will only happen once.
Decompressing 100% 4774 ms
Expanding 100% 12241 ms
Failed to create prime the NuGet cache. restore failed with: 1
  Restoring packages for D:\01_Toci\100_GIT\Passenger\Passenger.Api\Passenger.Api.csproj...
  Restoring packages for D:\01_Toci\100_GIT\Passenger\Passenger.Infrastructure\Passenger.Infrastructure.csproj...
  Restoring packages for D:\01_Toci\100_GIT\Passenger\Passenger.Core\Passenger.Core.csproj...
  Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: D:\01_Toci\100_GIT\Passenger\Passenger.Infrastructure\obj\project.assets.json
  Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: D:\01_Toci\100_GIT\Passenger\Passenger.Core\obj\project.assets.json
  Restore completed in 337,41 ms for D:\01_Toci\100_GIT\Passenger\Passenger.Core\Passenger.Core.csproj.
  Restore completed in 337,39 ms for D:\01_Toci\100_GIT\Passenger\Passenger.Infrastructure\Passenger.Infrastructure.csproj.
  Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: D:\01_Toci\100_GIT\Passenger\Passenger.Api\obj\project.assets.json
  Restore completed in 1,34 sec for D:\01_Toci\100_GIT\Passenger\Passenger.Api\Passenger.Api.csproj.

  NuGet Config files used:
      C:\Users\wojse\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
      C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

  Feeds used:
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```

dotnet --info output:

```
D:\01_Toci\100_GIT\Passenger\Passenger.Api>dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.4)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.4
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  af1e6684fd

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.15063
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.3
  Build    : a9190d4a75f4a982ae4b4fa8d1a24526566c69df
```

I've tried many things and nothing has helped:

- I installed .net core 2.0
- I changed package varsion to: 1.0.4 in .csproj
- I used command dotnet nuget locals -c all and after that dotnet restore

Can someone help me? :) Please

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6381 is relevant?

Comment: Or https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6758?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem after upgrading to VS 15.6. I was able to get around the issue by temporarily moving all SDKs newer than 1.0.4 out of the SDK folder (C:/Program Files/dotnet/sdk). Run dotnet restore, the cache population succeeds, then move the SDKs back.

Long term we will look to update our global.json files to pin a newer SDK, as the previous response indicated.

Comment: This works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 after installing 2.1.400

Comment: I would not have expected this, but I'm glad I found this answer.  Worked for my on Windows-10.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the 1.0.*  versions of the .NET Core SDK (not runtime!) which is no longer compatible once with features introduced in newer NuGet versions once those set up a global fallback folder.

Since you seem to have a 2.0 version installed, there is probably a `global.json` file pinning an old version of the SDK. Make sure you either pin a 1.1.* or 2.* version of the SDK or don't use a `global.json` file at all. You can still target .NET Core 1.0 using newer SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by editing global.json and replacing:

```
"version": "1.0.0-rc4-004771"
```

with:

```
"version": "2.0.0"
```

See:  [dotnet/cli issue #6758](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6758)  Jon Skeet refers to this issue in his comment on the question.